# LINQ: LinqDataSource How to do column Select in codebehind?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, select, linqdatasource

```
<asp:LinqDataSource 
    ContextTypeName="ExampleDataContext" 
    TableName="Products" 
    Select="new(Key as ProductCategory, 
            Average(Price) as AvePrice)"
    ID="LinqDataSource1" 
    runat="server">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Somehow my Select in .aspx file (as seen above) is not working: all columns are returned in the query result. So I will try to do that in code behind.

How do I perform the selection of the 2 fields in my LinqDataSource1_Selecting ()?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

//notice: condition is sample

```
int ave ;

Queryable<Object> IQ = ContextTypeName.TableName.Where(x=>x.Price <= ave);
```

OR

```
var Query = FROM objectNameSeleted IN ContextTypeName.TableName
            WHERE (your condition) SELECT objectNameSeleted
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<object> Products = (from p in ExampleDataContext.Products
                     where CONDITION
                     select p).ToList<object>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `GroupBy="ProductCategory"`.